# How to serve multiple domains with nginx using 1 droplet on digital ocean

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean

This is the default conf which works and is correctly served at my public domain.

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
server {
    server_name  localhost;
    listen       80;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index        index.html;
}
```

#### I have duplicated this 'conf' file and renamed to my webdomain name:

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/MYDOMAIN.com**

```
server {
    server_name  MYDOMAIN.com www.MYDOMAIN.com;
    listen       80;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index        index.html;
}
```

#### I have added symlink

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/MYDOMAIN.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

#### I have also updated hosts (Though not sure this is needed)

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 MYDOMAIN.com
```

#### I have pointed the domain name to my server via names.co.uk.

If you look you can see it correctly forwarded here:

https://codebeautify.org/name-server-lookup

```
MYDOMAIN.com    IN  1800    NS  ns3.digitalocean.com
MYDOMAIN.com    IN  1800    NS  ns1.digitalocean.com
MYDOMAIN.com    IN  1800    NS  ns2.digitalocean.com
```

#### I have restarted nginx

```
systemctl reload nginx
```

#### Status is good

```
systemctl status nginx
```

● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-12-19 17:39:06 UTC; 32min ago
Docs: man:nginx(8)

#### I can visit the ip address:

http://143.110.171.174/

This correctly serves the default conf file

#### But I cannot visit [www.MYDOMAIN.com](http://www.MYDOMAIN.com)

There is nothing returned. Can anyone advise what I'm missing?

Comment: seems like a DNS issue did you create an A record alongside with you NS records in DegitalOcean ?

Comment: @lotfio I have two domains I set up. Both from names.co.uk, both I set up to point the 3 domains to digital ocean. one of them shows the A record on digital ocean, where as easywebreader.com doesn't show it yet. I didn't manually set it. I assumed it updated itself via automation when transfering name server from names.co.uk. I wonder if it is just a matter of waiting for the complete transfer as its been less than 24hrs

Comment: easywebreader.com
3 NS / 1 SOA

otherdomain
1 A / 3 NS / 1 SOA

Comment: can you share a picture of your DegitalOcean DNS records ?

Comment: @lotfio yep. Just added to story

Comment: try adding an A record  `type: A`, `hostname @`,  `will direct to : your droplet ip`, `TTL : 3600`

Comment: @lotfio Thats it. it works. Its odd that I have to create that extra step.  I entered into the input field [hostname] as [www] so it came up as www.MYDOMAIN.com, and now it does indeed work. I've removed my references to actual website for privacy as its an experimental example. Thankyou very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have a missing `DNS A record` in you DNS rules

You can add an **A** record to your droplet as follow

- from the control panel, click the **Networking** in the main menu.
- then click on the domain you would like to manage.
- then select record type as **A**
- add hostname **@** ($ORIGIN)
- choose the droplet IP to redirects to
- choose a TTL 3600

wait for some minutes and you should get you domain working
for references you can check this link : https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/dns/how-to/manage-records/